# Recaptcha V3 gets a 0.3 or 0.1 score

Tags: php, jquery, recaptcha-v3

I have a problem with Recaptcha V3. I am almost alway's getting a negative score. I tested it from someone else's mobile device and he got a score of 0.3.
Now i have `if ($captchaResponse['success'] == '1' && $captchaResponse['score'] >= 0.1) {`
activated on all websites. Normally this is at 0.5. Nobody can login in my website without getting a negative score. Am i doing something wrong?

**This is the rest of my PHP code:**

```
$response = $_POST['token'];

// get cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api/siteverify');

// set method
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');

// return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// set headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
  'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
]);

// form body
$body = [
  'secret' => 'SECRET_KEY',
  'response' => $response,
];
$body = http_build_query($body);

// set body
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);

// send the request and save response to $response
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$captchaResponse = json_decode($response, true);
```

**And here is the Jquery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $(".recaptcha_form").on("submit", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
//recaptcha token code
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
      grecaptcha.execute('<?php echo RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY; ?>', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
        $('#token').val(token);
        $('#tokenPendingPage').val(token);
        $('#tokenAccount-account-overview').val(token);
        $('#tokenChangePasswordAfterLogin').val(token);
        $('#tokenRegisterCheckout').val(token);
      });
  });
});
});
```

**Maybe because i do this below (refreshing token every 3 seconds):**

```
function loadCaptcha() {
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
      grecaptcha.execute('<?php echo RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY; ?>', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
        $('#token').val(token);
        $('#tokenLoginHeader').val(token);
        $('#tokenPendingPage').val(token);
        $('#tokenAccount-account-overview').val(token);
        $('#tokenChangePasswordAfterLogin').val(token);
        $('#tokenRegisterCheckout').val(token);
      });
  });
}

function loadCaptcha2() {
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
      grecaptcha.execute('<?php echo RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY; ?>', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
        $('#tokenLoginHeader').val(token);
      });
  });
}
// Refresh token recaptcha every 3 seconds
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('xxx');
  loadCaptcha2();
  setTimeout(function() {
    loadCaptcha2();
    setInterval(loadCaptcha, 105 * 1000); // fire every 10 sec
  }, 90 * 1000); // fire only one time after 10 sec
});
```

Comment: The thing you are doing every x seconds it's just creating event listener which will run when event is fired.

Comment: @mputkowski Oke, but do you know why i and others are alway's getting a low score?